# Bugsnag doesn't send notification in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bugsnag

I've set up Bugsnag in development/production environment in Rails 4.

I'd love to test thing out in rails console.

```
Bugsnag.notify('test test test')
```

The config is following.

```
  Bugsnag.configure do |config|
    config.api_key = ENV['BUGSNAG_SECRET']
    config.notify_release_stages = ["production", "development"]
  end
```

Am I missing something important?

Comment: Note: I know nothing about bugsnag so this is a total guess.... does it actually do the notifications in test/dev environments? (some gems only do that in prod)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the doc!

Comment: Bugsnag does produces errors from development & prod & staging.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the bugsnag gem in gemfile.

Comment: Are you certain the api_key is set?  What do you get when you type `Bugsnag.api_key`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would confirm you have installed bugsnag gem to your Gemfile:
`bundle add bugsnag`

To correctly test `notify`, I would suggest trying something like this:

```
begin
  raise 'Something went wrong!'
rescue => exception
  Bugsnag.notify(exception)
end
```